# Rest output different to console vs. Tomcat localhost

Tags: java, rest, jersey, output

I have a simple rest get verb that reads a csv file and outputs some data. Sending data to console via System.out.println works great.

- Code:"English Name"
- AD:Andorra
- AE:"United Arab Emirates"
- AF:Afghanistan
- AG:"Antigua and Barbuda"
- AI:Anguilla
- AL:Albania

Now when I output that same data to my browser via a rest call I get the following.

- [Code:"English Name"
- , AD:Andorra
- , AE:"United Arab Emirates"
- , AF:Afghanistan
- , AG:"Antigua and Barbuda"
- , AI:Anguilla
- , AL:Albania
- ]

Where are the extra characters coming from? Here is my class.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getAllCountriesAndCodes() {
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("countryandcode.csv");

    String line;
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            myList.add(country[0] + ":" + country[1] + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            System.out.println(country[0] + ":" + country[1]);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return String.valueOf(myList);
}
```

I am using Java 7, Jersey 2.0 and IntelliJ 12 if that makes a difference. When I quickwatch myList, the data looks correct. Something else is formatting it? I package this in a war file and deploy it to Tomcat 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myList is a type of `List<String>` and you are returning it using `String.valueOf(myList);`
That will convert you myList to a form -

```
[Code:"English Name"
, AD:Andorra
, AE:"United Arab Emirates"
, AF:Afghanistan
, AG:"Antigua and Barbuda"
, AI:Anguilla
, AL:Albania
]
```

Instead try replacing your `String.valueOf(myList);` with the following,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (String text : myList) {
   sb.append(text);
}

return sb.toString();
```

[Check this link out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) - The ArrayList inherits AbstractList and AbstractList inherits AbstractCollection and so you get the toString() that way.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfect. One question. How did you know a List<String> gets converted to a form? I checked http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ and I couldn't find anything. Maybe in the Serialized Form documentation...

Comment: Check this out -
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29

Comment: I have amended the answer. Please have a look at the last part.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bunch JtheRocker.